# Is there a specific term for a tripod on wheels with handbrake in handle?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, terminology, tripod

A while back, I used a tripod which was on wheels, but had a handbrake built into the handle which made it quick and painless to unlock, move, relock the tripod into place. Additionally, for video recording there was no bump in the video when unlocking\relocking the wheels.

Does anyone know what term is used to market tripod dollies with this feature or a similar one?

Comment: @Hueco Most tripod dollies don't have connections to the handle of the tripod head for controlling the wheel locks.

Comment: What was the context you used the tripod — was it in a studio, was it for photography, was it for video or cinematography? Did the tripod seem easily portable, or was it large, heavy, and either non-portable or took a lot of time to set up? Was it actually a collapsible tripod, or was it more like a pedestal?

Answer (score 5):

Such a heavy duty tripod is typically referred to as a camera pedestal.

The wheels can be rotated for turns or locked in a parallel position to track in a straight line across the studio floor. Further, they can be set and locked to trace a circle around a distant centre of rotation. They can be unlocked but control of three independent, freely revolving wheel makes smooth operation a challenge. As you mentioned, holding a shot when live, is easier if you frame, lock to hold the shot, unlock to reframe. It had to be done smoothly and the friction locks could be adjusted to accommodate this easily.

(We television camera operators would have contests to see who could negotiate an obstacle course in the studio made with folding chairs and lighting stands. Points deducted for poor framing, less than smooth movement, and slow timing, etc.)

Some had housings for use in a studio context and some were able to collapse for easier transport for field locations and used minus the trucks in a fixed position.

Comment: Thinking about it for a nanosecond, such a thing would probably never be used for photography within the context of photographySE. It's a video thing.

Answer (score 0):

likely you are describing a Camera Dolly.

Answer (score 0):

The pedestal tripod is used in TV production, you can touch the wheel to guide the camera or raise and lower it. A tripod with a **hand crank** might be a better buy for photography.

- [Vinten Quattro SE](http://www.vinten.com/en/product/vinten-quattro-se) - U$85K

[image: Vinten Quattro SE]

Those are intended to hold [Teleprompters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprompter) as well as a heavy camera and [box lens](http://www.fujifilm.com/products/optical_devices/tv_cine/studio_field/). They offer precise crab and steer control from a central steering ring, and can be raised and lowered smoothly.

There are less expensive solutions, which mount to a tripod of your choice:

- [Mo-Sys handwheels](http://www.mo-sys.com/product/handwheels) - [POA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price_on_application)

  [image: Mo-Sys Handwheel]
- [ProAim Orion Geared Head](https://www.proaim.com/proaim-orion-geared-head.html) - U$2K

[image: ProAim Orion Geared Head]

Now all you need is a tripod with a gear-driven crank that allows you to elevate the camera above the level that the telescoping legs allow.

[image: Tripod with Hand Crank]